# np.isin - testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row considering the order

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, isinstance

I am using the following line to find if the rows of `b` are in `a`

```
 a[np.all(np.isin(a[:, 0:3], b[:, 0:3]), axis=1), 3]
```

The arrays have more entries along `axis=1`, I only compare the first 3 entries and return the fourth entry (idx=3) of `a`.

The possible error I realized is, that the order of the entries is not considered. Therefore, the following example for `a` and `b`:

```
a = np.array([[...],
              [1, 2, 3, 1000],
              [2, 1, 3, 2000],
              [...]])

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

would return `[1000, 2000]` instead of the of only `[1000]`.

How can I consider the order of the rows as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small `b` (less than 100 rows), try this instead:

```py
a[(a[:, :3] == b[:, None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0)]
```

Example:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 0, 5, 0],
              [1, 2, 3, 1000],
              [2, 1, 3, 2000],
              [0, 0, 1, 1]])

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]])

>>> a[(a[:, :3] == b[:, None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0), 3]
array([1000,    1])
```

Explanation:

The key is to "distribute" equality tests for all rows of `a` (the first 3 columns) to all rows of `b`:

```py
# on the example above

>>> a[:, :3] == b[:, None]
array([[[ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True],  # <-- a[1,:3] matches b[0]
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]]])  # <-- a[3, :3] matches b[1]
```

Be warned that this can be large: the shape is `(len(b), len(a), 3)`.

Then the first `.all(axis=-1)` means that we want all entire rows to match:

```py
>>> (a[:, :3] == b[:, None]).all(axis=-1)
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

The final bit `.any(axis=0)` means: "match any row in `b`":

```py
>>> (a[:, :3] == b[:, None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0)
array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

I.e.: "`a[2, :3]` matches *some* row(s) of `b` as well as `a[3, :3]`".

Finally, use this as a mask in `a` and take the column 3.

**Note on performance**

The technique above distributes equality for the product of the rows of a over the rows of b. This can be slow and use a large amount of memory if both `a` and `b` have many rows.

As an alternative, you may use `set` membership in pure Python (without subsetting of columns --that can be done by the caller):

```py
def py_rows_in(a, b):
    z = set(map(tuple, b))
    return [row in z for row in map(tuple, a)]
```

When `b` has more than 50~100 rows, then this may be faster, compared to the `np` version above, written here as a function:

```py
def np_rows_in(a, b):
    return (a == b[:, None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=0)
```

```py
import perfplot

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 5))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.5)
for ax, alen in zip(axes, [100, 10_000]):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (alen, 4))
    plt.sca(ax)
    ax.set_title(f'a: {a.shape[0]:_} rows')
    perfplot.show(
        setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, 20, (n, 3)),
        kernels=[
            lambda b: np_rows_in(a[:, :3], b),
            lambda b: py_rows_in(a[:, :3], b),
        ],
        labels=['np_rows_in', 'py_rows_in'],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(10)],
        xlabel='len(b)',
    )
plt.show()
```

[image: comparative performance]